# Fixing FORTRAN IV warning: "The number of arguments is incompatible with intrinsinc procedure, assume 'external' "

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I need to run an old FORTRAN IV code I was given (which is supposed to run just fine). I downloaded a trial version of Intel compiler and tried to compile the source file I was given with the command:

```
ifort  -f66 abel.for -o mycode
```

where abel.for is the name of the source file. I got a bunch of warnings and errors. I wanted to ask about the first warning I was given:

```
The number of arguments is incompatible with intrinsinc procedure, assume 'external'.  [KNOT]
```

where  KNOT is a function defined as:

```
C                                                                       AAOK0162
C  PROCEDURE FOR LOCATING THE SPLINE SECTION TO WHICH AN                AAOK0163
C  ARGUMENT BELONGS.                                                    AAOK0164
C        N    NUMBER OF KNOTS IN THE SPLINE REPRESENTATION              AAOK0165
C        U    KNOTS POSITION                                            AAOK0166
C        X    THE ARGUMENT WHOSE SPLINE SECTION IS SOUGHT               AAOK0167
C        I    THE NUMBER OF THE SMALLEST KNOT LARGER THAN X             AAOK0168
C                                                                       AAOK0169
      INTEGER FUNCTION KNOT(N,U,X)                                      AAOK0170
      IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)                                          AAOK0171
      DIMENSION U(1)                                                    AAOK0172
C TEST WHETHER POINT IN RANGE                                           AAOK0173
      IF (X.LT.U(1)) GOTO 990                                           AAOK0174
      IF (X.GT.U(N)) GOTO 990                                           AAOK0175
C ESTIMATE KNOT INTERVAL BY ASSUMING EQUALLY SPACED KNOTS               AAOK0176
      J=DABS(X-U(1))/(U(N)-U(1))*(N-1)+1                                AAOK0177
C ENSURE CASE X=U(N) GIVES J=N-1                                        AAOK0178
      J=MIN0(J,N-1)                                                     AAOK0179
C SEARCH FOR KNOT INTERVAL CONTAINING X                                 AAOK0180
      IF (X.GE.U(J)) GOTO 11                                            AAOK0181
2     J=J-1                                                             AAOK0182
      IF(X.LT.U(J)) GOTO 2                                              AAOK0183
      GOTO 7                                                            AAOK0184
1     J=J+1                                                             AAOK0185
11    IF(X.GT.U(J+1)) GOTO 1                                            AAOK0186
7     KNOT=J+1                                                          AAOK0187
      RETURN                                                            AAOK0188
990   KNOT=-1                                                           AAOK0189
      RETURN                                                            AAOK0190
      END                                                               AAOK0191
```

and the compiler error indicates the call of this function from a subsequent subroutine (line AAOK0211):

```
      SUBROUTINE ABEL1(N,IN,X,XN,A,B,C,D,YCALC)                         AAOK0201
      IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)                                         AAOK0202
      DIMENSION X(1),XN(1),A(1),B(1),C(1),D(1),YCALC(1)                 AAOK0203
      COMMON /R/ R                                                      AAOK0204
      COMMON /PI/ PI                                                    AAOK0205
      DO 70 L=1,IN                                                      AAOK0206
      R=X(L)                                                            AAOK0207
      IF(R.EQ.0.D0) R=1.D-6                                             AAOK0208
      YCALC(L)=0.D0                                                     AAOK0209
      IF (R.EQ.XN(N+1)) R=R-1.D-6                                       AAOK0210
      I=KNOT(N+1,XN,R)                                                  AAOK0211
      IF(I.EQ.-1) GOTO 70                                               AAOK0212
      IF(I.EQ.N+1) GOTO 99                                              AAOK0213
      DO 60 K=I,N                                                       AAOK0214
      X1=XN(K)                                                          AAOK0215
      X2=XN(K+1)                                                        AAOK0216
      S=3.D0*A(K)*DI1(2,X1,X2)+2.D0*B(K)*DI1(1,X1,X2)+C(K)*DI1(0,X1,X2) AAOK0217
      YCALC(L)=YCALC(L)+S                                               AAOK0218
60    CONTINUE                                                          AAOK0219
99    X2=XN(I)                                                          AAOK0220
      S=3.D0*A(I-1)*DI1(2,R,X2)+2.D0*B(I-1)*DI1(1,R,X2)                 AAOK0221
     *       +C(I-1)*DI1(0,R,X2)                                        AAOK0222
      YCALC(L)=-(YCALC(L)+S)/PI                                         AAOK0223
70    CONTINUE                                                          AAOK0224
      RETURN                                                            AAOK0225
      END                                                               AAOK0226
```

I wanted to ask what seems to cause this warning and if it is safe to just ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

`KNOT()` is a non-standard specific intrinsic function for the `NOT` function which accepts 8 byte integers (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3684/3_F77_Intrins.html ).

You can indeed ignore the warning in this case. Because the numbers and types of the arguments differ, the compiler will not call the intrinsic inadvertently, so it is safe. The problem would be if the compiler had a function which looks exactly the same but does something different. The `external` statement serves the purpose to prevent such collisions.

The thing you can do to suppress the warning is to tell the compiler you have your own external function `KNOT()` by placing

```
EXTERNAL *KNOT
```

in the declaration section of each compilation unit which calls `KNOT`, so for example,

```
SUBROUTINE ABEL1(N,IN,X,XN,A,B,C,D,YCALC)
      IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
      EXTERNAL *KNOT
```

The type should be all-right given your implicit typing rules, but you can specify it explicitly by

```
      INTEGER KNOT
```

**Note:** the `*` in `EXTERNAL *KNOT` means that not an intrinsic, but a user-supplied function should be used. This behaviour differs from modern Fortran! See http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0633a.htm In FORTRAN 77 and later use just `EXTERNAL KNOT`.

Comment: alternately,rename the user function to avoid the conflict.

Comment: True, but then some other compiler will come up with some other function name which will clash, it is not worth follow them in my opinion.

Comment: when I added the line EXTERNAL KNOT after the declaration of each function which calls KNOT I got the compilation error:  " this intrinsic procedure reference contains too many arguments.   [KNOT]" ,  for each line calling the KNOT function.  How can I fix this?

Comment: @user4861528 Ok, it is indeed a FORTRAN 66 specific thing http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0633a.htm See the edit for the solution.

Comment: The usage of `EXTERNAL` to override intrinsic was evidently an `f77` addition.  The `*` now locks you in to using `ifort` with `-f66` .. ( renaming it to something like `MYKNOT` starts to look more attractive )

Comment: Personally, I would just ignore the warning, but you are right. In other case the signatures may not differ and the compiler might call the intrinsic. The best would be to convert the code to F77, but that may be a lot of work.