# Compiling with gfortran: undefined reference to iargc_

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I'm using gfortran [GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)] on a Fedora 20 x86_64 to compile a bunch of Fortran 77 code which refers to 'iargc' function in the following manner:

> bin2D2nc.f:31:    integer iargc,strlen1
>
> bin2D2nc.f:32:    external iargc,strlen1
>
> bin2D2nc.f:44:    i=iargc()

When the make script reaches the compilation comand bellow,

```
gfortran -O3 -ffixed-line-length-132 -fall-intrinsics -I/home/santiago/Install/netcdf_sam/include   -o bin2D2nc -I./SRC ./SRC/bin2D2nc.f ./SRC/hbuf_lib.f ./SRC/cape.f ./SRC/cin.f -L/home/santiago/Install/netcdf_sam/lib  -lnetcdf -L/usr/lib64 -lpthread
```

I receive these messages:

> bin2D2nc.f:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `iargc_'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: ** [bin2D2nc] Erro 1

I'm not the author of this code. As far as I know, I set up correctly the library paths in the [makefile](http://pastebin.com/BgmhqbFb).

I have found that 'iargc' is a routine for backward compability with GNU Fotran 77, but I don't understand it deeply.

Could someone give some advise to surpass this problem?

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add a version tag where necessary to distinguish.

Comment: IARGC is not an external function. Or it could be one, but you are not providing it. It is an intrinsic. You must use `INTRINSIC IARGC` or just delete `IARGC` from the `EXTERNAL` statement. This is a remnant of FORTRAN 66, not 77. I will close this question as a duplicate after I find the original.

Comment: @vladimir-f, thanks for your valuable comments. I think you could leave both questions, since they're not exactly the same. Beginners, like me, probably won't see those questions are so similar.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that and put an answer here as well in the end.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is very similar to [Fixing FORTRAN IV warning: "The number of arguments is incompatible with intrinsinc procedure, assume 'external' "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012052/fixing-fortran-iv-warning-the-number-of-arguments-is-incompatible-with-intrins) but the difference is that in the other question there was an external function present and the similarity with an intrinsic was inadvertent, but you are calling the intrinsic on purpose.

The statement

```
EXTERNAL IARGC
```

meant that `IARGC` is an external or an intrinsic function in FORTRAN 66, but in "modern Fortran" 77 and later it means that it is an external function only.

But you need to call the intrinsic function https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/IARGC.html .

You should use

```
 INTRINSIC IARGC
```

or even just delete IARGC from the `EXTERNAL` statement without adding anything else. The compiler will then stop searching for a non-existent external function and will use the intrinsic.

A final note, `IARGC` itself is not standard Fortran, ut it shouldn't matter here.