# Undefined reference to fdate_

Tags: compilation, fortran, gfortran, fortran77

When installing a software called snob, there is a file `date.f'

```
function date(n)
 character*24 fdate,date
 external fdate
 date=fdate()
 return
end
```

Compiling with fort77, I encountered such error:

```
fort77-4511-1.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `fdate_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried both gfortran and g77 without success. I tried the flags `-fno-second-underscore` with fort77,  and `-fno-scoring` for gfortran but still no success.

Others suggested me to refer to [Compiling with gfortran: undefined reference to iargc_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003926/compiling-with-gfortran-undefined-reference-to-iargc/35004268)

Firstly, I replaced `external` with `intrinsic` and get:

```
/usr/bin/f77  -c date.f
   date:
Error on line 17: Declaration error for fdate: unknown intrinsic      function
/usr/bin/f77: aborting compilation
make: *** [date.o] Error 25
```

Then I deleted `fdate` from `external` statement and get:

```
/usr/bin/f77  -c date.f
   date:
Error on line 17: syntax error
/usr/bin/f77: aborting compilation
make: *** [date.o] Error 25
```

Will anyone help me with that?

Comment: I don't know why you should have this problem, this legacy (not Fortran 77) function is supported by gfortran https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FDATE.html (try without any options about underscores) although it would be preferable to change to the standard date_and_time.

Comment: why are you using f77? do you have to? if not, use f90 or 2003 standards

Comment: You must show the code. Would vote to close, but saving my vote for later. My bet is it is a duplicate. Is there `external fdate ` anywhere in the code? If yes, it is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003926/compiling-with-gfortran-undefined-reference-to-iargc/35004268

Comment: @Fl.pf. It is some kind of third party software so there is no choice...

Comment: I don't see that the presence or absence of the technically required external fdate (since is this not an f77 intrinsic) much affects the answerability of this.

Comment: @tim18 Have you read my link at all? Extetnal is not required, it is *prohibited*.

Comment: I don't need to use f77, but when using other compilers, there are more errors. I think it maybe because f77 cannot identify fdate_ function, which is supported by gfortran.  I the problem is solved under Windows system using IVF, although I don't know why. Thank all of you very much!

Comment: If you want to know why, you must show the code. I even suggested what to look for, so it could be easy.

Comment: nm on the library and the .o file maybe worthwhile.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you and sorry to reply late. There is external fdate in the code. I've tried your idea, using intrinsic fdate or just deleting it, but still does'n work. I will post the code in another question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Tell us what happened after you deleted the line or after you put `intrinsic`. Tell us what exactly is your compiler. Try to run `fort77 -v` and tell us what it prints.

Comment: Tell us what happened after you deleted the line or *especially* after you put intrinsic. Tell us what exactly is your compiler. Try to run fort77 -v and tell us what it prints.

Comment: you should delete the *entire line*  `external fdate`. get rid of it. then show the exact error message. As a shot in the dark try `call fdate(date)` (  *instead of* `date=fdate()`  )

Comment: Clearly the `f77` does not have this function. You really should use a modern compiler like gfortran. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @VladimirF I tried gfortran and got a bunch of errors `undefined reference to *`. Seems the software is developed based on f77. If convenient, may I have your email address and send the software to you? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First, if `fdate` is a non-standard intrinsic function of your compiler, the `external` statement is illegal as explained in [Compiling with gfortran: undefined reference to iargc_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003926/compiling-with-gfortran-undefined-reference-to-iargc/35004268)

You claim that deleting the line and putting `intrisic` instead did not help. In that case I assume your compiler does not have `fdate()` as an intrinsic function, but you should still tell us what exactly the compiler printed when you tried that.

In that case you are simply out of luck. You have to find the code for `fdate()` somewhere, or you have to change the code so that it does not call `fdate()` or you must implement `fdate()` yourself.

I cannot implement `fdate()` here for you, that is too much for an answer on this server.

The final possibility is to use a better compiler. Ditch the ancient and long obsolete `fort77` from the past century and using something from this century. For example the free `gfortran` or `g95` or buy some commercial compiler. It is up to you.

---

Here is a working example:

```
print *, date(1)

contains

  function date(n)
   character*24 fdate,date
!    external fdate
   intrinsic fdate
   date=fdate()
   return
  end

end
```

compile and run:

```
> gfortran fdate.f90 
> ./a.out 
 Fri Oct 21 10:12:25 2016
```

with gfortran 4.8.3

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience! I've tried gfortran and g95, but without luck. Maybe I should look for fdate() from other compilers and interpret it by my self. Thank you again for your kind help!

Comment: Did you delete the `external `? You HAVE TO. Edit you question and describe what you tried in steps including the commands and the error messages.