# Compiling an old fortran code in gfortran of ubuntu 18.04

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I am new to fortran and I want to compile a code which was written in 1988, http://www.seg.ethz.ch/software/velest.html.
 I used this command :

`f77 -o velest velest.f`

and this error was displayed

```
velest.f:10165:45:

      write(ifil,'(''North  rotate= '',f6.1,)') rotate
                                         1
Error: Unexpected element ‘)’ in format string at (1)
velest.f:4384:25:

   call RAYPATH(1,1,1,1.,1.,1.,1.,nl,thk,h,v,vsq,
                     1
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument ‘x’ at (1) (rank-1 and scalar) [-Wargument-mismatch]
```

Then I found the place of the first error inside the code and removed "," of "f6.1". After compiling again this time, these errors appeared :

```
velest.f:4384:25:

   call RAYPATH(1,1,1,1.,1.,1.,1.,nl,thk,h,v,vsq,
                     1
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument ‘x’ at (1) (rank-1 and scalar) `[-Wargument-mismatch]`
/tmp/ccQk4MAf.o: In function `datetime_':
velest.f:(.text+0x310c): undefined reference to `time_'
velest.f:(.text+0x3120): undefined reference to `ctime_'
velest.f:(.text+0x3149): undefined reference to `sprintf_'
/tmp/ccQk4MAf.o: In function `cputimer_':
velest.f:(.text+0x3abf): undefined reference to `clock_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

For solving that I followed the instruction of this websitehttp://nota.tw/2011/04/21/adjust-velest-in-ubuntu/
but after compiling this time, this error appeared :

```
velest.f:4384:25:

   call RAYPATH(1,1,1,1.,1.,1.,1.,nl,thk,h,v,vsq,
                     1
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument ‘x’ at (1) (rank-1 and scalar) [-Wargument-mismatch]
/tmp/cc7WrZmF.o: In function `datetime_':
velest.f:(.text+0x3119): undefined reference to `ctime_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would be grateful if someone could answer to my question.

Comment: You mention gfortran, but are using fort77 the later looks to me a conversion script from Fortran to C and running afterwards gcc. What happens when you use: `gfortran -o velest velest.f`?

Comment: Welcome, you cannot just show the error message, we need to see the relevant parts of the code as well ([mcve]). For the final error you have to show us the part of code that calls CTIME. It is not a standard Fortran procedure and it is not compatible between different compilers. Gfortran uses this definition https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CTIME.html

Comment: The external link to the code is *not* enough. We need to see your code *after* your adjustments! It is quite likely just forgot to change the line which uses CTIME.

Comment: In this line "RAYPATH(1,1,1, 1.,1.,1.,1., ...)", the dummy (formal) arguments for 1.0... are four arrays (x,y,z,vel), which I think gfortran is complaining. To make it work, I guess we need to modify the code a bit more (like using temporary arrays x, y, z, vel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format string is invalid.  There is a comma appearing in `f6.1,)`.  Thus, gfortran is expecting another edit descriptor not a right parenthesis.  If you delete that erroneous comma, the code compiles.  Note, this could be a bug in gfortran so you may want to interact with gfortran developers.

Comment: Please note this is well known and the required changes are explained in the link http://nota.tw/2011/04/21/adjust-velest-in-ubuntu/. The OP did indeed apply those changes and he no longer has this problem in his second version of the code. The final problem he has is elsewhere and is likely only cased by wrong or incomplete application of the changes recommended in the link.

Comment: The problem with the invalid format is not mentioned in that note, so it seems that it is not that well known.  Given the messages about missing ctime_ when linking, it is a clear indication the source code has an EXTERNAL statement, which means gfortran's CTIME will not be used.  Delete the EXTERNAL statement.

Comment: `external ctime` is indeed possible, the OP should have shown us his/her updated code, but would be a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003926/compiling-with-gfortran-undefined-reference-to-iargc/35004268 I am basically waiting for the code to close it as a duplicate. You are right the trailing comma is not in the link but was identified and fixed by the OP soon enough and I would consider it just a noise or distraction here.

Comment: I checked the source code.  It contains `exernal ctime`.  Almost all symbols exported from libgfortran have a _gfortran_` prefix.  `external ctime` tells gfortran that the use will supply the routine.  If that statement were missing, then gfortran would link to _gfortran_ctime.

Comment: Of course it would, it is in the duplicate link...  But you only checked the original link, you couldn't check the code the OP is compilng because (s)he didn't share it. Anyway, I will close it and it could be reopened if needed.