# Fortran code (.f95) compiles fine in Windows g95 compiler but incorrectly in Ubuntu gfortran

Tags: windows, ubuntu, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile an .f95 fortran script so it can run on Ubuntu. The script is available here -> [Link to zip file containing .f95 script](https://nicholas.duke.edu/people/faculty/katul/LSM_Heavy_Particles_2015.zip)

It compiles and runs fine when I switch over to Windows and compile using g95 compiler. The .exe file produced also runs fine in Ubuntu through wine.

However if I try to compile to make an Ubuntu file, it does not work properly. I don't get a compile error, but if I run the resultant file, either the program gets stuck in an infinite loop, or the output is all wrong. It's difficult for me to see where it is going wrong because I did not write the original code and only have a shaky understanding of Fortran, but it seems to be something to do with the numbers being calculated wrong leading to very large/small/inappropriately negative output (sorry to be so vague).

I am running 16.04 xenial ubuntu and gfortran 5.4.0.

Any help/thoughts appreciated this is driving me up the wall! Thanks

Code below for quick reference:

```
    ! Seed dispersal model of of Duman et al. (2015)
    ! Instructions and expample are found in:
    ! https://nicholas.duke.edu/people/faculty/katul/research.html
    ! in 'Library of Functions and Utilities'

    ! Author:           Tomer Duman

    ! Version:          Version 2

    ! Date:             October 22, 2015

    ! References:       Duman, T., Trakhtenbrot, A., Poggi, D.,
    !                   Cassiani, M., Katul, G., Dissipation
    !                   Intermittency Increases Long-Distance
    !                   Dispersal of Heavy Particles in the Canopy
    !                   Sublayer,
    !                   accepcted to Boundary-Layer Meteorology



    program LSmodel
    implicit none

    real :: sec,ran,gasdev                        ! random generator variables
    real :: x,y,z,u,v,w,ut,vt,wt,t,dt             ! simulation variables
    real :: wg                                    ! seed parametes
    real :: Um,sigma_u,sigma_v,sigma_w,uw         ! wind statistics variables
    real :: dvaru_dz,dvarv_dz,dvarw_dz,duw_dz     ! wind statistics variables
    real :: dissip_m,TL                           ! vector over the range of ustars
    real :: zs,zg,zmax                            ! release height & boundaries
    real :: Ainv,C0inv                            ! inverse parameters
    real :: C0,A,b,au,av,aw,dt_on_TL              ! LS model parameters
    real :: dz_max,dt_max                         ! time step limit
    real :: CT,beta                               ! Crossing Trajectories correction
    real :: C_chi,chi,TKE,T_chi,omega             ! DI parameters
    real :: a_ln,b_ln,sigma_chi,dissip_s          ! DI parameters
    real :: rhop,rho,r,g,gt,Re,AIP,Cd,nu          ! IP parameters
    real :: up,vp,wp,upt,vpt,wpt,vr,dt_ip,alpha   ! IP parameters
    integer :: seed                               ! random generator variables
    integer :: pnum                               ! simulation parameters
    integer :: i,j,jj,n,ii                        ! counting parameters
    integer :: n_ip,IP=1                          ! IP parameters
    character(len=80) :: filename
    real, allocatable,dimension(:) ::  z_vec,Um_vec,sigma_u_vec,sigma_v_vec,sigma_w_vec,uw_vec
    real, allocatable,dimension(:) ::  dvaru_dz_vec,dvarv_dz_vec,dvarw_dz_vec,duw_dz_vec,dissip_m_vec

    ! setting the random generator seed
    seed=7654321
    sec=0.0
    seed=seed+2*int(secnds(sec))

    ! input
    open (21,file='input_parameters.txt')
    read (21, *), x,C0,wg,zs,zg,beta,dt_on_TL,y,sigma_chi,C_chi,r,rhop,alpha,rho,nu
    close(21)
    pnum = int(x)  ! number of released seeds
    n = int(y)     ! size of the input flow stats
    wg = -1.0*wg   ! seed terminal velocity [m/s]
    !zs            ! seed release height [m]
    !C0            ! universal constant
    !beta          ! crossing trajectories parameter
    !zg            ! ground height [m]
    !sigma_chi     ! the standard deviation of chi (dissipation intermittency)
    !C_chi         ! constant for T_chi calc
    !r             ! particle radium [m] - set to 0 for no IP
    !rhop          ! particle dry density [kg/m^3]
    !alpha         ! drag parameter (Cd = 24/Re_p*(1+alpha*Re_p))
    !rho           ! fluid density [kg/m^3]
    !nu            ! fluid viscosity [m^2/s]
    C0inv = 1.0/C0
    g = 9.81
    if (r==0.0) then
       IP = 0
    end if

    ! limiting parameters to prevent too big jumps in a time-step
    dz_max = 0.1
    dt_max = 0.1

    open(unit=12,file='res.dat', form='formatted')
    open(unit=13,file='res_traj.dat', form='formatted')

    ! allocate
    allocate(z_vec(n))
    allocate(Um_vec(n))
    allocate(sigma_u_vec(n))
    allocate(sigma_v_vec(n))
    allocate(sigma_w_vec(n))
    allocate(uw_vec(n))
    allocate(dvaru_dz_vec(n))
    allocate(dvarv_dz_vec(n))
    allocate(dvarw_dz_vec(n))
    allocate(duw_dz_vec(n))
    allocate(dissip_m_vec(n))

    ! load normalized stats
    open (22,file='input_flow.txt',form='formatted')
    read (22,*) z_vec
    read (22,*) Um_vec
    read (22,*) sigma_u_vec
    read (22,*) sigma_v_vec
    read (22,*) sigma_w_vec
    read (22,*) uw_vec
    read (22,*) dvaru_dz_vec
    read (22,*) dvarv_dz_vec
    read (22,*) dvarw_dz_vec
    read (22,*) duw_dz_vec
    read (22,*) dissip_m_vec
    close(22)

    zmax = z_vec(n)

    do i=1,pnum

          t=0.0      ! initiate time and location
          x=0.0
          y=0.0
          z=zs

          do j=2,n    ! interpolate
             if ((z>=z_vec(j-1)).and.(z<=z_vec(j))) then
                sigma_u=((sigma_u_vec(j-1)-sigma_u_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+sigma_u_vec(j-1)
                sigma_v=((sigma_v_vec(j-1)-sigma_v_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+sigma_v_vec(j-1)
                sigma_w=((sigma_w_vec(j-1)-sigma_w_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+sigma_w_vec(j-1)
             end if
          end do

          ! velocity initiation
          u=gasdev(seed)*sigma_u
          v=gasdev(seed)*sigma_v
          w=gasdev(seed)*sigma_w
          chi=sigma_chi*gasdev(seed)-0.5*sigma_chi*sigma_chi

          up=0.0    ! initiating particle velocity from rest
          vp=0.0
          wp=0.0

          do     ! time loop

             do j=2,n    ! interpolate
                if ((z>=z_vec(j-1)).and.(z<=z_vec(j))) then
                   Um=((Um_vec(j-1)-Um_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+Um_vec(j-1)
                   uw=((uw_vec(j-1)-uw_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+uw_vec(j-1)
                   duw_dz=((duw_dz_vec(j-1)-duw_dz_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+duw_dz_vec(j-1)
                   sigma_u=((sigma_u_vec(j-1)-sigma_u_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+sigma_u_vec(j-1)
                   sigma_v=((sigma_v_vec(j-1)-sigma_v_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+sigma_v_vec(j-1)
                   sigma_w=((sigma_w_vec(j-1)-sigma_w_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+sigma_w_vec(j-1)
                   dvaru_dz=((dvaru_dz_vec(j-1)-dvaru_dz_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+dvaru_dz_vec(j-1)
                   dvarv_dz=((dvarv_dz_vec(j-1)-dvarv_dz_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+dvarv_dz_vec(j-1)
                   dvarw_dz=((dvarw_dz_vec(j-1)-dvarw_dz_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+dvarw_dz_vec(j-1)
                   dissip_m=((dissip_m_vec(j-1)-dissip_m_vec(j))/(z_vec(j-1)-z_vec(j)))*(z-z_vec(j-1))+dissip_m_vec(j-1)
                end if
             end do

             CT = sqrt(1.0+beta*beta*wg*wg/sigma_w/sigma_w)  ! crossing trajectories correction
             TL = 2.0*sigma_w*sigma_w*C0inv/dissip_m/CT      ! added CT effect
             TKE = 0.5*(sigma_u*sigma_u+sigma_v*sigma_v+sigma_w*sigma_w)

             ! -------- Adding dissipation intermittency model --------
             omega=dissip_m*CT/TKE           ! added CT effect
             T_chi=1.0/omega/C_chi
             dt=min(dt_on_TL*TL,dt_on_TL*T_chi,dt_max)
             a_ln = -(chi + 0.5*sigma_chi*sigma_chi)/T_chi
             b_ln =  sigma_chi*sqrt(2.0/T_chi)
             chi = chi+a_ln*dt+b_ln*sqrt(dt)*gasdev(seed)
             dissip_s = dissip_m*exp(chi)
             ! --------------------------------------------------------

             A = 2.0*((sigma_u*sigma_u)*(sigma_w*sigma_w)- uw*uw)
             Ainv = 1.0/A
             b = sqrt(C0*dissip_s*CT)   ! added CT effect

             au = (b*b)*(uw*w - u*sigma_w*sigma_w)*Ainv + 0.5*duw_dz &
                  + Ainv*(sigma_w*sigma_w*dvaru_dz*u*w - uw*dvaru_dz*w*w &
                  -uw*duw_dz*u*w + sigma_u*sigma_u*duw_dz*w*w)
             av = (-(b*b)*v + dvarv_dz*v*w)/2.0/sigma_v/sigma_v
             aw = (b*b)*(uw*u - w*sigma_u*sigma_u)*Ainv + 0.5*dvarw_dz &
                  + Ainv*(sigma_w*sigma_w*duw_dz*u*w - uw*duw_dz*w*w &
                  -uw*dvarw_dz*u*w + sigma_u*sigma_u*dvarw_dz*w*w)

             ut = u + au*dt + b*sqrt(dt)*gasdev(seed)
             vt = v + av*dt + b*sqrt(dt)*gasdev(seed)
             wt = w + aw*dt + b*sqrt(dt)*gasdev(seed)

             u = ut
             v = vt
             w = wt

             ! -------- Adding IP model --------
             if (IP==1) then
                dt_ip = dt*0.01
                n_ip = 100
                upt = up
                vpt = vp
                wpt = wp
 100            do ii=1,n_ip
                   vr = sqrt((u+Um-upt)*(u+Um-upt)+(v-vpt)*(v-vpt)+(w-wpt)*(w-wpt))
                   if (vr>1000.0) then
                      dt_ip = dt_ip*0.5
                      n_ip = n_ip*2
                      upt = up
                      vpt = vp
                      wpt = wp
                      goto 100
                   end if
                   Re = 2.0*r*vr/nu
                   Cd = 24.0*(1.0+alpha*Re)/Re
                   AIP = 3.0*rho*Cd/8.0/rhop/r
                   gt = g*(rhop - rho)/rhop
                   upt = upt + AIP*vr*(u+Um-upt)*dt_ip
                   vpt = vpt + AIP*vr*(v-vpt)*dt_ip
                   wpt = wpt + (AIP*vr*(w-wpt)-gt)*dt_ip
                end do
                up = upt
                vp = vpt
                wp = wpt
             end if
             ! ----------------------------------
             if (IP==0) then
                up = Um+u
                vp = v
                wp = w+wg
             end if

             x = x + up*dt
             y = y + vp*dt
             z = z + wp*dt

             if (i<50) then    ! saving trajectories of 50 seeds
                write(13,*) i,t,x,y,z
             end if

             if (z>zmax) then
                exit
             end if

             if (z<zg) then
                dt = (z-zg)/(w+wg)
                z = z - (w+wg)*dt    ! ensure that z = zg at landing
                x = x - (u+Um)*dt
                y = y - v*dt
                write(12,*) i,x,y
                exit
             end if

             dt_max = dz_max/abs(w+wg)
             t = t+dt

          end do

          if (mod(i,100)==0) then
             print *, 'wg = ',abs(wg),' zr = ',zs,' pp ',pnum-i
          end if

    end do

    end program LSmodel



   !***********************************************************************
   ! This function generates Gaussian Random Deviates from uniform deviates.
   ! The function is from Press et al. (1992 p. 280).
   function gasdev(idum)
   implicit none
   integer :: idum, iset
   real :: gasdev,fac, gset, rsq, v1, v2, ran
   save :: iset, gset
   data iset/0/
   if (iset.eq.0) then
1        v1=2.*ran(idum)-1.
         v2=2.*ran(idum)-1.
         rsq=v1**2+v2**2
         if (rsq.ge.1. .or. rsq .eq. 0) go to 1
         fac =sqrt(-2.*log(rsq)/rsq)
         gset=v1*fac
         gasdev=v2*fac
         iset=1
   else
        gasdev=gset
        iset=0
   end if
   return
   end function gasdev

   !***********************************************************************
    !uniform random generator between 0 and 1
    function ran(idum)
    implicit none
integer, parameter :: K4B=selected_int_kind(9)
integer(K4B), intent(inout) :: idum
real :: ran
integer(K4B), parameter :: IA=16807,IM=2147483647,IQ=127773,IR=2836
real, save :: am
integer(K4B), save :: ix=-1,iy=-1,k
if (idum <= 0 .or. iy < 0) then
    am=nearest(1.0,-1.0)/IM
    iy=ior(ieor(888889999,abs(idum)),1)
    ix=ieor(777755555,abs(idum))
    idum=abs(idum)+1
end if
ix=ieor(ix,ishft(ix,13))
ix=ieor(ix,ishft(ix,-17))
ix=ieor(ix,ishft(ix,5))
k=iy/IQ
iy=IA*(iy-k*IQ)-IR*k
if (iy < 0) iy=iy+IM
ran=am*ior(iand(IM,ieor(ix,iy)),1)
end function ran
```

The command I am using to compile in Ubuntu is

```
gfortran LSmodel.f95 -o LSmodel.o
```

There is no compile error, it compiles fine, but then on running the program afterwards the problems start.

I have included a typical expected output from running the program below (res.dat):

```
       1   21.8583908       8.47351170    
       2   1.44100714      -8.78142548    
       3   1154.74109      -265.975677    
       4   8.41901588       2.71606803    
       5   84.5189209      -20.4699802    
       6   86.3176270      -18.4299908    
       7   133.826874       43.4905090    
       8   4.37516022      -2.50738835    
       9   1.31284332      -2.65105081    
      10   1.96412086       2.85013437    
      11   4.34823132      -3.83539009    
      12   40.1227837      -6.60268879    
      13   3.88699961       2.63749719    
      14   7.08872795       1.51467562    
      15   4.72280264       2.63384581    
      16  0.667112768       1.37209761    
      17   2.09094667       1.23296225    
      18   4.72298622      -1.43766475    
      19   1.04012501      -3.13314247    
      20   1.91324210      0.957163811    
      21   1.99065340      0.611227572    
      22  -2.09086251      -1.41756165    
      23  -1.46836996      -5.55722380    
      24   2.41403580       2.18929257E-02
      25   3.96990728      -4.91323137    
      26   1.54687607     -0.527718127    
      27   8.24332428      -1.48289037    
      28   4.81600523      -8.87443924    
      29   2.39538932      0.323360980    
      30   192.294815      -36.7134209    
      31   24.6190643       21.7993126    
      32 -0.124062911       3.44432545    
      33   16.6237335      -8.54020786    
      34   50.0964355      -3.29175758    
      35   5.23409462       2.14592004    
      36   6.62141275       1.47515869    
      37   10.7572327      0.307090789    
      38   63.5973434      -47.7124138    
      39   74.9621201       2.11509633    
      40   4.46293068      -1.64074826    
      41   11.7773390       10.0654907    
      42   8.26941204       6.84578228    
      43  0.917451978       2.69560647    
      44  -2.21521306       15.0752039    
      45   8.18219483E-02  -2.06250334    
      46  0.279425710      -3.10328817    
      47   4.37736464      -1.37771702    
      48  -2.85058951      -1.79835165    
      49   5.08391476       2.68537569    
      50  -4.27199030     -0.642364025
```

Comment: Coud you try inserting a new line `external ran` just below `data iset/0/` in the routine `gasdev`, and also comment out the line `seed=seed+2*int(secnds(sec))` ? (to avoid interference with intrinsic `ran` in gfortran and also to confirm whether it gives the same result with Windows/g95)

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and [mcve]. We need to see your exact error messages. Please copy the exact output of the compiler including the command you entered.

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012052/fixing-fortran-iv-warning-the-number-of-arguments-is-incompatible-with-intrins

Comment: On my computer (with gfortran-7.3), the program freezes because intrinsic ran( seed ) in gfortran returns some constant value while not modifying seed (= idum), and the loop in gasdev never gets finished (depending on the seed chosen)... So there is no error message and I'm afraid the (wrong) result probably becomes system-dependent.

Comment: @roygvib thankyou for your input. I made the changes to the file and reran in both ubuntu and windows and can confirm that the output is the same (and the issues I was getting with ubuntu seem to have gone!)

Is there a way of fixing the problem so the seed can be changed?

Comment: @VladimirF, there is no error message as the code compiles fine, but I have included the command used if that is helpful

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Have you read the Q/A I linked? It is definitely relevant. I do not understand your last comment: *Is there a way of fixing the problem so the seed can be changed?*

Comment: Yes I have read it. I think perhaps I could be more clear about what the expected output is; perhaps I can add a typical expected output. But there is no output for when it does not work - I used to have some output of strangely high/negative numbers which I could have included but I don't have them any more the few more recent times I have tried to run it it just gets stuck in a loop and produces no output. There are no error messages. The reason I posted the full code is because I am not familiar with Fortran and so I literally have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: I mean a way of having the program not get stuck in a loop while also having the seed change so it does not produce the same output every time.

Comment: It seems to work OK if I put the `seed=seed+2*int(secnds(sec))` back in, but I am worried that there is 'interference with intrinsic `ran`' that I do not understand

Comment: @agorapotatoes If the program gives the same output on Ubuntu and Windows, I think it is now okay to uncomment the line "seed=seed+2*int(secnds(sec))" to get more "random" results (depending on system time). If there is some known result for this program (e.g. written on papers), I think it would be very useful to try to reproduce it for further validation... (Also, if really necessary, it is also possible to replace ran() with more recent intrinsic [random_number()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fNUMBER.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling your program with `gfortran -Wall` gives

```
test.f90:297:4:

     function ran(idum)
    1
Warning: 'ran' declared at (1) is also the name of an intrinsic.
It can only be called via an explicit interface or if declared 
EXTERNAL. [-Wintrinsic-shadow]
```

which means that the user-defined routine `ran()` has the same name as intrinsic [ran()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs//gfortran/RAN.html) in gfortran. So we need to declare it as an external routine (to tell the compiler that this is a user-defined one):

```
   function gasdev(idum)
   implicit none
   integer :: idum, iset
   real :: gasdev,fac, gset, rsq, v1, v2, ran
   save :: iset, gset
   data iset/0/
   external ran     !<--- here
   ...
```

It is necessary to include `external ran` in all routines that utilize the user-defined `ran`. (In this program, only the `gasdev()` routine is using it.) To avoid such interference, it is usually better to use a bit more specific name other than `ran`, `rand`, etc (for example, rand_uniform() or ranranran() might be good). It would also be very nice if the routine is included in a module to avoid such problems, so please search the net for how to use modules for more details (if necessary...)

Comment: When building legacy code with modern compilers (F90 and beyond), it helps to rename variable, subroutine, and function names which conflict with newer intrinsic functions. I see that a lot with `sum`, `index`, and `gamma`. It generally takes about a minute to search & replace over a project, less if you're using an IDE which has a global rename command, though this may get tripped up if the IDE isn't smart enough to look in Fortran `include` files.